# Apache redirect all child directories except one

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

So, I have the following URLs:

```
www.example.com/parent/child1
www.example.com/parent/child2
www.example.com/parent/child3
www.example.com/parent/cool-feature
www.example.com/parent/product
etc...
```

I need to redirect all children except for `child2` to a new domain.

---

So far I have come up with:

```
RedirectMatch ^/parent(?!/child2) http://www.new-example.com/parent/
```

This is working for:

```
www.example.com/parent/child2
```

but not for:

```
www.example.com/parent/child2/
```

due to the trailing slash

---

To no avail, I have tried:

```
RedirectMatch ^/parent(?!/child2/) http://www.new-example.com/parent/
RedirectMatch ^/parent(?!/child2\/) http://www.new-example.com/parent/
RedirectMatch ^/parent(?!/child2)/ http://www.new-example.com/parent/
RedirectMatch ^/parent/(?!child2)/ http://www.new-example.com/parent/
```

Comment: With your rule, neither  `/parent/child2` nor `/parent/child2/` will be redirected

Comment: I agree with @DusanBajic, your initial `RedirectMatch` directive appears to work OK for me. Do you have any other directives that are perhaps conflicting? Are `child1`, `child2`, etc. directories, files, or URLs mapped to a front controller? I guess the later, so you have perhaps have existing mod_rewrite directives? Also, clear your browser cache in case an erroneous 301 has previously been cached.

Comment: @DusanBajic Yes, that is what I seek. Unfortunately `/parent/child2/` is redirecting; I do not want it to redirect.

Comment: @DocRoot Yes, there are several other directives but to avoid conflicts in targeting the same parent I am trying to make this directive work with a non-existent (404) `/parent-test/child2/` structure. It succeeds for `/parent-test/child2` (404 happens) but `/parent-test/child2/` fails to be caught and redirects. This is for a 6 year old website built on a homebrew framework with a front controller. I've been clearing my cache every time. I really prefer not to tamper with the old stuff because a few pages need to still work even though the site has been redesigned onto a new domain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, by itself, your initial directive should work as intended. None of `/parent/child2`, `/parent/child2/` or `/parent/child2/anything` should be redirected.

However, since you have "other directives", including a "front controller", you might have a conflict. Particularly since your front controller probably uses mod_rewrite and `RedirectMatch` is a mod_alias directive. mod_rewrite will always execute first, despite the apparent order in `.htaccess`. But these redirects should execute first, before the front controller.

Try changing this to a mod_rewrite redirect and ensure it is near the top of your `.htaccess` file, before the front controller.

```
RewriteRule ^parent(?!/child2) http://www.new-example.com/parent/ [R=302,L]
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer, it looks very promising but unfortunately I won't be able to do more testing until Monday. Till then, cheers!

Comment: Following the advice in this answer I unfortunately have had no success in suppressing the redirect when a trailing slash is present. I am going to contact the vendor and see if they can figure it out. Since this answer is correct in theory and I am not at liberty to share all of the rules in the htaccess file, I will gladly accept this answer. Thanks again!